# Linked List: Deleting nodes with chosen data

Tags: c++

I have problem with deleting chosen node from my list. The task was to delete all the nodes that include data chosen by user and count them. For example to delete all the nodes that includes 3 and count them. Function should return integer with the number of deleted nodes. My code for function pop node and for pop all nodes including specific data is here. I use Visual Studio 2012 and debugging says some pointers are pointed into space. Memory failed to read. What's the problem?

```
void pop(Node *  head, Node *  pointer) //delete node with given pointer
{
    Node * p = head;
    if (pointer == head)
    {
        head = p->next;
        delete p;
    }
    else
    {
        while( p->next != pointer )
        {
            p = p->next;
        }
        p->next = pointer->next;
        delete pointer;
    }
}

int pop_all(Node *  head, float data_out) //delete all nodes with proper data
{
  Node * p = head;
  int counter = 0;
  while(p->next != NULL)
  {
    if (p->data == data_out)
    {
        pop(head,p);
        counter++;  
    }
    else
    {
        p = p->next;
    }

  }

  return counter;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure this should be tagged as C.

Comment: Your code will not properly check a list of 1 element (p->next == NULL) first time through.

Comment: Note that after popping an element once through `pop_all()` you want have a `p->next` because the exact same node you're on is now deleted .

Comment: In addition, you are directly comparing against the value of a float. Consider using epsilons or perhaps a different data type as direct float compares often don't work the way you think they will.

Comment: I did not. It was post mistake.

Answer (score 0):

First of all a question: why a home brew list and not std::list.

Then the constructive criticism: pop function has the wrong signature. If the deleted node if the first of the list there is no way for the function to tell the caller that head changed. Usually I implement like this:

```
void pop(Node **head, Node *pointer)
{
    for ( ; *head ; head = &((*head)->>next)
        if (*head == pointer)
        {
            Node *temp = *head ;
            *head = temp->next ;
            delete p ;            
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `pop_all()`, after a call to `pop(head,p)` where `head != p`, `p` points to memory you just `delete`d.  Then at the top of the `while` loop you ask for `p->next`, which is undefined.